# Finding a solution to an equation and plotting it

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have this equation that I want solve explicitly so that $\omega$ is dependent of $k$ like this $\omega (k)$ and then plot it on a plane for k, but I have no idea which function to use. This is the equation.

> $4\omega^4+2\omega^2-2e^{-ik}+2e^{ik}+7$ = 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
w[k] /. Solve[
  4 w[k]^4 + 2 w[k]^2 - 2 Exp[-I k] + 2 Exp[I k] + 7 == 0, w[k]] 

Plot[ReIm[%], {k, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was working on this as you solved it. Better than I would have done. You missed a 4 of the first term. Also looks pretty  if you plot k between 0 and 20.

Answer (score 3):

Amplifying on David's answer

```
sol = w[k] /. 
   Solve[4 w[k]^4 + 2 w[k]^2 - 2 Exp[-I k] + 2 Exp[I k] + 7 == 0, w[k]] // 
  FullSimplify

(* {-(1/2) Sqrt[-1 - Sqrt[-27 - 16 I Sin[k]]], 
 1/2 Sqrt[-1 - Sqrt[-27 - 16 I Sin[k]]], -(1/2) Sqrt[-1 + 
   Sqrt[-27 - 16 I Sin[k]]], 1/2 Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[-27 - 16 I Sin[k]]]} *)

Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[sol], {k, 0, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> (Outer[StringForm["`1` `2`", #2, #1] &, Range[4], {Re, Im}] //
     Flatten)]
```

[image]

Even with the colors it is difficult to see the separate solutions. Separating them out,

```
Grid[
 Partition[
  Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[sol[[#]]], {k, 0, 20},
     PlotLegends -> {Re, Im}] & /@ Range[4], 2],
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]